# Personal issues preventing from joining new job

Tags: professionalism, communication, new-job, job-change, unprofessional-behavior

I am finding myself in a difficult situation. I took a new job in June with a start date in middle August. I am from a EU country and I should relocate in UK for my new activity. Due to a health issue problem of my parents I had to move the start date to middle September, but now the problem has recurred and I am uncomfortably close to the start date. I don't think they will grant me another start date delay and, giving the circumstances, I don't think I will be able to join at the concorded day.
How can I explain the situation without looking fickle?

Comment: Only partly related: Did you make sure that as a EU but non-UK citizen, you are still able to work/stay at your new job after of Brexit? Otherwise, relocating for only a few months might not be worth it (given that the date doesn't get pushed back forever).

Comment: @Dirk in theory yes, with a lot more of bureaucracy and paperworks. Practically, nobody knows for certain, since there is still no deal and no final decision on immigration measures.

Answer (score 3):

If it's concerning health you could simply say "That the previous health problem relapsed and you need more time". Which probably has 2 results: Either the company comply and extend or in urgent need and don't want to wait anymore.

Alternatively, you could pay another person to take care of your parent if it's not serious health issue such as stroke which resulting in half paralyze. You could pay for a nurse to help take care while you're working. My parent also does this for taking care of my grandparent since they need to work and unable to take care while they're working.

Answer (score -1):

If they need that post to start, then you could well loose the post and it won't be their fault.

You have pushed the start date which they accepted, if you ask again, they do not have to accept and you are, or could be, in breach of contract which could be sufficient grounds for termination.

Comment: Well, I never said it was their fault. They've been quite understanding until now. I took a decision back in June basing on certain circumstances, that changed dramatically after a few weeks.

Comment: @Userno1234 When I mentioned fault, it was not the past but the future...